# Training time changes sometimes for the same notebook on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colabs to train my model using GPU.
Even i use the same code, the execution time for an epoch differs significantly.
It differs between 5 minutes and 25 minutes.
I tried to reset the runtime. 
I check the memory, it seems same.
I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the type of GPU you are using is changing. You can check by running the command `nvidia-smi`. Here's an example:

[image]

A P100 is the fastest GPU available. You might consider subscribing to [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) for priority access to P100s.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I think it assigns the GPU randomly. I restart the connection until i get a good GPU.

Comment: What is the best way to get the same run time at each run?